# can't enable ACL

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem

I started here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

I see that acl is enabled on all mounts on my disk by default, but `$ mount | grep acl` yields nothing.

I tried exlicitly enabling acl in /etc/fstab and remounting root, but this didn't work either.

Is it possible for acl to be working if `mount` doesn't show it? I clearly have an acl entry on a file but I'm getting permission denied.

```
user@host:~$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          6a12565d-9b50-4250-be1d-f7d9fe20461f
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              12156928
Block count:              48627712
Reserved block count:     2431385
Free blocks:              38642088
Free inodes:              11984210
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon Mar 14 19:39:19 2022
Last mount time:          Thu Apr 28 12:21:11 2022
Last write time:          Thu Apr 28 12:21:10 2022
Mount count:              8
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Mon Mar 14 19:39:19 2022
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          161 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ACL can be working without `mount` showing it, because it's working on my machine. The files I was denied access to were broken symlinks.